# Bootstrap Glyph is aligning slightly off-centre from circular border

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The following code uses the bootstrap glyphicons and a 50% border radius to show icons in a circle. However, the icons aren't perfectly central (slightly to the left), despite `text-align` attribute having been set. Why is this?

```
<div class="glyphicon-ring white-ring"> 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-bordered" style="color:white"></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
   .glyphicon-ring {
      width: 90px;
      height: 90px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border: 6px solid #54534A;
      color: #54534A;
      display: inline-table;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 40pt;
    }
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/27wp0a39/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add `line-height;` in span style & `margin` in div  as like below

```
.glyphicon-ring {
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
margin:0 auto 0 auto;
border: 6px solid #54534A;
color: #54534A;
border-radius:50%;
text-align:center;
width: 90px;
height: 90px;
font-size:40pt;
}
```

span style is:

```
<div class="glyphicon-ring white-ring"> 
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-bordered" style="margin:0; line-height:77px; text-align: center;"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `line-height: 90px;` on `.glyphicon`:

```
.glyphicon{
    line-height: 90px;
    vertical-align: middle; /* To insure vertical align */
}
```

P.S.: The icon is still going to look slighty positioned to the left due the icon width. In this case, you can use `transform:translateX(2px);` in `.glyphicon` class to fix it.